# vue js setTimeout in created method

Tags: vue.js

```js
    methods: {

        showAlert() {
            alert("alert");
        }

    },

    created() {
        setTimeout(this.showAlert(), 5000)
    }
```

My codes are in here. I want to set time out in created area. But browser does not see setTimeout. it always runs when the page renders. Its not waiting. How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run the method inside the setTimeout callback like :

```
 created() {
        setTimeout(()=>{
        this.showAlert()
         }, 5000)
    }
```